# What happens during the insertion, deletion and update in sql?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, b-tree

I would like to know a few things regarding mysql architecture.
1. How sql process insert, delete, update operations in an indexed table?
2. It is said that changes are only made in the change buffer when the index page is not in the buffer pool. So if changes are made after the buffer pool loads the concerned index page, then it has to alter the same page in disk as well. right? So an operation has to be done in three different places?
3. How NULL values are indexed? where would they be stored in a b+tree?
4. If we update a data which is the clustered index, then when will it be updated in the disk?
5. What happens during bulk loading?

Comment: If this question is just about [tag:mysql], why the [tag:sql-server] tag?

Comment: These are quite some questions. Some people might resign writing an answer, due too much content is required. You also need someone confident in answering each aspect questioned. Why didn't you structure and split the topics in different questions?

Answer (score 3):

How to process insert/update/delete...

1. Fetch (and cache) index block(s) needed for locating the row(s) to be updated/deleted, or the blocks where new row(s) will be inserted.
2. Fetch the data block(s).  Note that all indexes include the `PRIMARY KEY`, which is clustered with the data.
3. Modify the data block(s) to reflect the changes.  Also deal with remembering the old data -- in case of an eventual `ROLLBACK`.
4. Update unique index blocks (that includes the PK).
5. Store non-unique index changes in the change buffer.  (As you noted.)

The change buffer is designed to be a 'transparent' to the actual index blocks.

- A lookup by an index will always 'do the right thing', whether the entry is in the CB or not.
- Folding of CB entries back into actual index blocks is done in the 'background' and/or when running out of room.  (The CB defaults to 1/4 of the buffer_pool, I think.)
- Sufficient information is stored in the transaction log, such that a crash will not the loss of pending index updates.
- Clearly the CB was invented for performance.  An index update can be delayed, and meanwhile, takes a lot less space (often only a few dozen bytes) than the index block (16KB) that needs updating.  Multiple changes (usually) can be applied to a single index block -- This is the main savings.  But note, because of randomness, UUIDs, MD5, etc, cannot make good use of the CB.  A non-unique index on the current datetime/timestamp is a case where the CB's buffering really shines.

(Sorry, my knowledge of the CB is a bit vague for the level at which you are asking.  I suggest you read the code.)

`NULL`...  I believe that is treated as a separate value that sorts before all non-null values in the B+Tree.  But to confuse the issue, there is a flag determining whether nulls are treated as equal to each other.  And there are restrictions on `PRIMARY`/`UNIQUE` keys.

Related to NULL...  When doing `PARTITION BY RANGE` on some variant/function of `DATE` or `DATETIME`, invalid dates turn into `NULL`, which is explicitly stored in the 'first' partition.  Newbies are often puzzled as to why partition pruning does not seem to work.  (Recommended partial workaround:  have a 'first' partition that is otherwise empty.)

Clustered *and* `UNIQUE` indexes...  All(?) write operations must check *all* unique indexes, hence the CB is not involved with such.  Note:  In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is always clustered and unique and cannot(?) have `NULLs`.

Bulk loading...  I find that a 100-row `INSERT` will run 10 times as fast as 100 individual `INSERTs`.  (This is due to parsing, etc.)  But at the low level, a batch insert or `LOAD DATA` is just a bunch of individual inserts.  So, the above discussion applies.

Bonus answers...

"IODKU" (`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`) is pretty much follows the 1..5 steps above.  In locating the row to update, it discovers whether to update or insert, then proceeds accordingly.

`REPLACE` is really a shorthand for `DELETE`, plus `UPDATE`.  But note this anomaly...  If there are two unique keys on the table, a one-row `REPLACE` might delete 2 rows before inserting the 1 row.

Comment: Thank you for spending time in answering the question. could you suggest where I can learn more about such internal things? @Rick James

Comment: Percona.com blogs on a lot of things.  I think Jeremy Cole has a blog on the CB.