# When will the mysql update it's index tree after an update or insertion?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

In oracle it is said that the change in data will be stored as logs in change buffer. Only after the index page is loaded to the buffer pool, It is updated. If that's the case, when exactly does that happen? What happens if the same data is read before the index page is updated?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367493/what-happens-during-the-insertion-deletion-and-update-in-sql -- If you don't think it is a dup, please rephrase the question to ask something that I did not answer in that question.

Answer (score 0):

As it can be read in https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_buffer_cache.htm#TGDBA294, the result of reading with non-updated indexes much depends on cache tuning.

Comment: That's Oracle databases, not MySQL.  Any similarity in design is coincidental.