# Update on Index Column

Tags: mysql, indexing, b-tree

while updating index tree,

> MySQL will update the existing tree node directly?
> (or)
> Creates a new node and insert it,while the exiting index node will be
> deleted?

Comment: [What happens during the insertion, deletion and update in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367493/what-happens-during-the-insertion-deletion-and-update-in-sql) Delete - insert.

Comment: Perhaps if you specified what database layer or phenomenon you are dealing with.  There is pressure to reuse disk space because every write is very time-consuming. But when writing to disk it isn't possible to write something less than a block. Deleting is just marking the place as free for other data, so it doesn't cost anything. The second part of your question could be considered as true for locks, caches, or high-level access. Better is the first part of your Q. From a B-tree perspective is this answer also relevant. Data are merged to a existing node and an empty node is deleted.

Comment: As the 'dup' says, it is complex in a different way.  As David says, the main goal is to minimize I/O while assuring that indexes are viable at all times.  The "Change Buffer" is the main 'secret sauce'.